# create a lineal-log-log-lineal partition of interval [a,b] in matlab, but matching steps

Tags: matlab, vector, partitioning

i want to create a vector `x` from `a` to `b`, in the following way.
I have an interest point `c` , `a<c<b`, and a ratio `r`.

1.- From `a` to `c-r` the step is lineal, that is, given `n1`,

```
x1=linespace(a,c-r,n1);
```

2.- Likewise from `c+r` to `b`, given `n4`;

```
x4=linespace(c+r,b,n4);
```

3.- From `c-r` to `c`, i want logarithmic/exponential step, that is, given `n2`,

```
L=linespace(exp(c-r),exp(c),n2);
x2=log(L);
```

4.- From `c` to `c+r` it's analogous to the previous one, but with a decreasing exponential, given `n3`:

```
K=-log(c+r)/r;
fun=fcnchk([num2str(c),'*exp(',num2str(K),'*(x-',num2str(c),'))']);
L=linspace(feval(fun,c),feval(fun,c),n3);
ifun=fcnchk(['(1/',num2str(K),')*log(x/',num2str(c),')+',num2str(c)]);
x3=feval(ifun,L);
```

Finally:

```
x=[x1(1:end-1) x2(1:end-1) x3(1:end-1) x4];
```

Now, my isue is that, if `dx1=x1(end)-x1(end-1)` and `dx2=x2(2)-x2(1)`, i want to choose `n2`, or use a proper `ce^(kx)` function such that `dx1=dx2`. Analogouly, `dx3=x3(end)-x3(end-1)` should be equal to `dx4=x4(2)-x4(1)`.